# Getting the delta time (minimum value - actual value) of an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a cartesian RDD which allows me to filter a RDD on a certain time range, but I need to get the minimum value of the RDD so I can calculate the delta time of each record to the entry that occurred first.

I have a case class that is made up like the below:

```
case class auction(id: String, prodID: String, timestamp: Long)
```

and I put together two RDDs, one that contains the auction of note, the other contains the auctions that occured in that time period as below:

```
val specificmessages = allauctions.cartesian(winningauction)
                  .filter( (x, y) => x.timestamp > y.timestamp - 10 && 
                  x.timestamp < y.timestamp + 10 && 
                  x.productID == y.productID )
```

I would like to, in the specificmessages function, be able to add a field which will contain the delta between each record and the auction timestamp that has the minimum value.

Comment: What is the source of the minimum `timestamp`? Is it computed for all auctions in `allauctions` / `winningauction` or per time window?

Comment: it should be the minimum timestamp in the filtered result of the `allauctions.cartesian(winningauction)` where the auctions are filtered on timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataFrames like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Convert RDDs to DFs
val allDF = allauctions.toDF
val winDF = winningauction.toDF("winId", "winProdId", "winTimestamp")

// Prepare join conditions
val prodCond = $"prodID" === $"winProdID"
val tsCond = f.abs($"timestamp" - $"winTimestamp") < 10

// Create window
val w = Window
  .partitionBy($"id", $"prodID", $"timestamp")
  .orderBy($"winTimestamp")

val joined = allDF
  .join(winDF, prodCond && tsCond)
  .select($"*", first($"winTimestamp").over(w).alias("mintimestamp")
```

Using plain RDDs

```
// Create PairRDDs
def allPairs = allauctions.map(a => (a.prodID, a))
def winPairs = winauctions.map(a => (a.prodID, a))

allPairs
    .join(winPairs) // Join by prodId -> RDD[(prodID, (auction, auction))]
    // Filter timestamp
    .filter{case (_, (x, y)) => (x.timestamp - y.timestamp).abs < 10} //
    .values // Drop key -> RDD[(auction, auction)]
    .groupByKey // Group by allAuctions -> RDD[(auction, Seq[auction])]
    .flatMap{ case (k, vals) => {
        val minTs = vals.map(_.timestamp).min // Find min ts from winauction
        vals.map(v => (k, v, minTs))
    }} // -> RDD[(auction, auction, ts)]
```

Comment: Hi Zero, unfortunately I am in a production environment that still is using spark 1.2 and CDH 5.3.x., and I don't have access to Data Frames within spark.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand underlying logic (if not please provide example input and expected output) but I've added a solution using plain RDDs.

Comment: Thanks @Zero323 you seem to have the spec right on the money :)